# хищники и паразиты

Tags: грамотная-речь

хищники и паразиты в чем разница

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Хищники** питаются добычей, убитой ими в результате охоты.

**Паразиты** - организмы, которые питаются кровью или тканями *живой* жертвы, которая становится для них средой обитания.